# moving buttons along with the camera in swift

Tags: ios, swift, button, sprite-kit, skcameranode

I am working on a game where my player moves when buttons are pressed, so I made the buttons children of the camera. However when my camera moves, the buttons appear where they should, but when I press again nothing happens. 
Here is some code about the camera and buttons.

```
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

    enumerateChildNodes(withName: "//*", using: { node, _ in
        if let eventListenerNode = node as? EventListenerNode {
            eventListenerNode.didMoveToScene()
        }
    })


    world = childNode(withName: "World")!
    player = (world.childNode(withName: "player") as! Player)


    spikes = world.childNode(withName: "spikes") as! SKSpriteNode
    spikes.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: spikes.size.width/2, height: spikes.size.height/2))
    spikes.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Spikes
    spikes.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false

    self.addChild(cameraNode)
    camera = cameraNode
    cameraNode.position = CGPoint(x: 0 , y: 0)
    cameraToMove = cameraNode.position.y - player.position.y
    setupCamera()




    left = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "leftButton")
    right = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "rightButton")
    jump = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "upButton")


    jump.size.width /= 2
    jump.size.height /= 2
    left.position = CGPoint(x: -self.size.width/2 + left.size.width, y: -self.size.height/2 + left.size.height)
    right.position = CGPoint(x: left.position.x + 2 * right.size.width, y:(camera?.position.y)! - self.size.height/2 + left.size.height)
    jump.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width/2 - jump.size.width, y:(camera?.position.y)! - self.size.height/2 + left.size.height)

    cameraNode.addChild(left)
    cameraNode.addChild(right)
    cameraNode.addChild(jump)


}

  override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first
    let location:CGPoint = (touch?.location(in: self))!
    if left.contains(location){
        move(forTheKey: "left")
        print("left")
    }
    else if right.contains(location){
        move(forTheKey: "right")
        print("right")
    }
    else if jump.contains(location){
        player.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 240))

    }else{
        print(location)
    }


}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first
    let location:CGPoint = (touch?.location(in: self))!
    if left.contains(location){
        player.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
        print("left removed")
    }
    else if right.contains(location){
        player.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
        print("right removed")
    }
    else if jump.contains(location){
        print("jump removed")
    }else{
        print("else")
        print(location)
        print(left.position)
        print(convert(left.position, from: cameraNode))
        print(convert(left.position, to: cameraNode))
        print(camera?.position.y)

        player.physicsBody?.velocity.dx = 0
    }
}
```

As you can see I have a lot of prints to check the left button position.
In the beginning the y position is at -577. after the camera moves, the button appears where it should at -450. but cant press it because its position is still at -577. I also tried to update its position by converting the position to the camera, but didn't work.
I would really appreciate if someone can help.

Comment: Show your [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the touch as it is relative to your camera, not relative to the scene, since your buttons are in the coordinate system of the camera.

Change `let location:CGPoint = (touch?.location(in: self))!` to `let location:CGPoint = (touch?.location(in: self.camera))!`

then your buttons should function properly.